# Trouble in Layout of Java Swing Gui

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm a newbie of java and still learning. And here is the trouble I'm in while making the GUI.
Its format supposes to be like this.

[image: image 1]

But instead of the above GUI, it's like this

[image: image 2]

My tutor said using the GridLayout for the main panel to show 3 other panels, then using the FlowLayout inside 3 panels. I did it, but it's still not working. By the way, how I can make the component being down the line? Please help and thank you.
Here is my code of the class showing in image 2.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import model.*;

public class AddPanel extends CustomPanel
{
    private Cinema cinema;
    private Movies movies = new Movies();
    private Theatres theatres = new Theatres();
    private Sessions sessions = new Sessions();
    private AddMoviePanel panel1 = new AddMoviePanel();
    private AddTheatrePanel panel2 = new AddTheatrePanel();
    private AddSessionPanel panel3 = new AddSessionPanel();
    public AddPanel(Cinema cinema)
    {  
        this.cinema = cinema;
        setup();
        build();
    }

    public void setup()
    {  
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1)); 
    }   

    public void build()
    {   
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);
        add(panel3);
    }
    private class AddMoviePanel extends JPanel
    {
        private JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
        private JTextField cost = new JTextField(5);
        private setListener listener = new setListener();
        public AddMoviePanel()
        {
            setup();
            build();
        }

        public void setup()
        {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        }

        public void build()
        {
            addTitle("Add a Movie");
            addPair("Movie name: ", name);
            addPair("Movie cost: ", cost);
            addButton("Set", listener);
        }
        private class setListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                double thecost = Double.parseDouble(cost.getText());
                String thename = name.getText();
                movies.add(thename,thecost);
            }
        }
    }
    private class AddTheatrePanel extends JPanel
    {
        private JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
        private JTextField gold = new JTextField(5);
        private JTextField regular = new JTextField(5);
        private setListener listener = new setListener();
        public AddTheatrePanel()
        {
            setup();
            build();
        }

        public void setup()
        {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        }

        public void build()
        {
            addTitle("Add a Theatre");
            addPair("Theatre name: ", name);
            addPair("Number of gold seats: ", gold);
            addPair("Number of regualr seats: ", regular);
            addButton("Set", listener);
        }
        private class setListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int thegold = Integer.parseInt(gold.getText());
                int theregular = Integer.parseInt(regular.getText());
                String thename = name.getText();
                theatres.add(thename,thegold,theregular);
            }
        }
    }
    private class AddSessionPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
        private JTextField movieid = new JTextField(5);
        private JTextField theatreid = new JTextField(5);
        private JTextField time = new JTextField(5);
        private JLabel sessiontime = new JLabel("Enter Session Time - 0 for 9am, 1 for 12noon, 2 for 3pm or 3 for 6pm");
        private JTextField goldprice = new JTextField(5);
        private JTextField regularprice = new JTextField(5);
        private setListener listener = new setListener();
        public AddSessionPanel()
        {
            setup();
            build();
        }

        public void setup()
        {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        }

        public void build()
        {
            addTitle("Add a Session");
            addPair("Session name: ", name);
            addPair("Movie ID: ", movieid);
            addPair("Theatre ID: ", theatreid);
            add(sessiontime);
            addPair("Session time: ", time);
            addPair("Price for a gold seat: ", goldprice);
            addPair("Price for a regular seat: ", regularprice);
            addButton("Set", listener);
        }
        private class setListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int thegold = Integer.parseInt(goldprice.getText());
                int theregular = Integer.parseInt(regularprice.getText());
                int themovieid = Integer.parseInt(movieid.getText());
                int thetheatreid = Integer.parseInt(theatreid.getText());
                int thetime = Integer.parseInt(time.getText());
                String thename = name.getText();
                cinema.addSession(thename,themovieid,thetheatreid,thetime,thegold,theregular);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Check it is complete and verifiable b pasting the code into a new project/package & compiling/running it before posting. Note that the custom class names sound like method names. A class name should not include verbs.

Comment: You should look at the JTabbedPane class.

Comment: *I'm a newbie of java and still learning* - Learn to walk before your run. By this I mean, write some code, then test. Write more code then test. In this example you have basically 3 identical panels. Problem is you wrote the code for all 3 and none of them work. So whatever fix you need means you will need to make the fix 3 time. So the better approach is to create one panel. Get it working and then create the other 2. Then if you have a question to ask in the forum you have simpler code to post and we will be better able to help.

Comment: The code you posted looks reasonable but we don't have the full context of the code and how the layout managers are used. We don't know what the `CustomPanel` is. Maybe that is the problem. We don't know what the methods `addTitle*()`, `addPair()` or `addButton() do. Also, I would suggest you can use a `TitledBorder` on each of your panels instead of using a label. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: *By the way, how I can make the component being down the line?* - you need to use a different layout manager. The FlowLayout always displays components at the top. Work on solving one problem at a time. Also, when you use a GridLayout. Don't specify both the row/column value. Specify one or the other. In this case you want a single column so you would use `new GridLayout(0, 1)`.

Comment: @camickr thank you so much, the tutor creates a skeleton project, then I need fill code to complete it. So that's why it also confuses me. those methods (addTitle, addPair, addButton) from CustomPanel which basically (as my tutor said) helps reduce duplication of code. I think i will take your advice and do some work first then ask again later